# Prevent spring batch proxifying specific bean

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have spring batch bean which is created with bean factory:

```
<bean id="inputFolder"
      factory-bean="fileSystemService"
      factory-method="getPath" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="#{jobParameters['file.input']}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <array></array>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But the problem when I execute my batch job this bean is wrapped with interface `org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject` and `interface org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean`

How can I explicitly prevent this bean from being proxified? I just want in this case to get clean class.

Comment: You cannot as you are creating a scoped proxy, which by definition is a proxy.

Comment: Why do you want a "clean class" ?

Comment: @Asoub class which is returned by 'getPath' method as-is. Not wrapped in  JdkAopProxy

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, this is how spring works, especially when you have such factory bean with factory method.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring, a singleton bean, without any behavior added is just that bean.